# The difference between -include and just include in makefile

Tags: makefile, include

In the makefile script, I see the following

```
-include Toplevel.mk
```

and sometimes, I see the following

```
include buildconfig/Rules.mk
```

They both seem to include makefiles, but I don't know the difference.

Could you tell me the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the description in the manual not clear enough?

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html